# vb.net multiple tables in dataset error

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

i'm trying to update sql server with a table from a dataset. 
when i'm loading  2 tables like the example below its work excellent, TABLE 1 first - then TABLE 2.
but if i load TABLE 2 before TABLE 1 - i get an error message.
it seems that the update command affect only the last table that was loaded to the dataset.

what is the solution ?

ERROR MESSAGE:
"Additional information: Missing the DataColumn 'ProjectName' in the DataTable 'Cities' for the SourceColumn 'ProjectName'."

```
Public da As New SqlDataAdapter
Public ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Public cn As SqlConnection
Public SQLCommand As SqlCommand

Private Sub loadPart()

    Dim strConnection As String = "Server=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BooKKeeping;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    cn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim CommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

    '// PART 1 - LOAD TABLES TO DATASET

    cn.Open()

    '// LOAD TABLE 1 
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Projects"
    SQLCommand = New SqlCommand(strSelect, cn)
    da.SelectCommand = SQLCommand
    da.Fill(ds, "Projects")

    '// LOAD TABLE 2
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Cities"
    SQLCommand = New SqlCommand(strSelect, cn)
    da.SelectCommand = SQLCommand
    da.Fill(ds, "Cities")

    cn.Close()

    '// PART 2 - ADD NEW RECORDS

    Dim row As DataRow = ds.Tables("Cities").NewRow()

    row("City") = "A"
    ds.Tables("Cities").Rows.Add(row)

    '// PART 3 - UPDATE SERVER 

    cn.Open()

    da.Update(ds, "Cities")

    cn.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use one data adapter to try to work with more than one database table.  If you want to work with two different tables then use two different data adapters.  That means two command builders too.